# Memory allocation: multiple instances of WCF hosted in a Windows Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, memory

We have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application that consumes services from a WCF service developed using asp.net 4.0 and hosted in a Windows service.
The WCF is PerSession and the session is very heavy: after about 80 users connected the RAM of the service reach 2GB. After enlarging the process memory with

```
editbin /largeaddressaware wcfservice.exe
```

we can serve about 100 users.
With a base of about 1000 users we need 10 servers to satisfy all calls :-(
So, because the Application server has 16GB RAM can we install multiple instances of the WCF server in order to limit the number of servers?
There is some alternative to avoid consume that RAM?

Thanks

Comment: Is your app built as 32bit?

Comment: Yes. We cannot move to 64 bit at the moment because we use third party libraries not available for 64bit platform.

Comment: Graq a profiler - a memory profiler. Figure out what uses the memory - you likely will find some atrocious code, OR that you just need to rearchitect (multiple instances that each handle i.e. 64 users max).

Comment: Unfortunately, the memory allocation is correct. The session for each user weighs a lot.

Comment: Do you mean your service should maintain 1000 session at the same time? To make best use of your service, you could consider  InstanceContextMode.PerCall if your service don't need to maintain session data. If you only want to serve all the user (don't need to serve them at the same time) , to prevent  excessive use of memory, you could  consider [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicethrottling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicethrottling)

Comment: I apologize, maybe I'm not clear. Our web application is developed in ASP.NET 4.0 and authenticate users with Windows Authentication. Webapp instance a WCF service which load and maintain in memory an user profile that is heavy. The profile is unloaded when user close webapp. Each WCF service can host max 80 users connected, 100 users with LARGEADDRESSAWARE. At the moment we cannon move to 64bit WCF. So we think to create several WCF service in the same server. It is madness in your opinion? Can you give some idea? Thanks